# How can I use a variable from views.py in a base template for multiple templates?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

In a Django application I have several html pages with a similar structure. I am already using a base_site.html template for all my project but for these other pages I would like to use a second template to create tables. These tables could have more or less rows and columns than others.
My idea was that the functions in `views.py` would send a list of the headers for any given page together with a dict of the data to populate the table, then in the html page I would iterate the list of headers to place the headers in the table then I would iterate the dict to populate the table with the data.

How can I have a `table-template.html` to use a variable say `headers` from every function in `views.py` whenever they are called?

Something like `table-template.html`

```
<h1>TEST</h1>
    <table>
        <tr bgcolor="#ccc">
            <th>{% for h in headers %} {{ h }} {% endfor %}</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Considering that every function in `views.py` would return its own `headers` list
Then how can I use it in any of the html pages

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

{% include "table-template.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% for key,value in mydict.items %}
 <table> 
  <tr>
    <td>{{ value }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The table-template.html could be use a slight change since you want each value in a  tag

```
<h1>TEST</h1>
    <table>
        <tr bgcolor="#ccc">
            {% for h in headers %}
            <th> {{ h }} </th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This will create the correct table headers for you. You can send the headers list from your view render method in the context dictionary.

Feel free to comment if this doesn't give the complete answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to find a solution by creating a template that inherits my `base_site.html` and on all my other templates I will inherit my `new_template.html`. So it's kind of a grand parent template inheritance.
I just included all the variables I want in the template (which are all named equally across all functions in `views.py`) and when the template is extended in a new page it gets the values of the variables from the respective function in `views.py`.

Comment: Sounds good, you can also pass template names from the backend through the context in the render function and include the template names dynamically. In that way you will have more power and structure to choose your partial templates.

Comment: We normally call the templates that you include in other templates as partial html. And give these a naming convention as `_templatename.html` or `partial_templatename.html`

Comment: This sounds really interesting. I would like to see an example of how it works. But if you include a template instead of extending (I'm assuming that's what you meant) you can't have different blocks right?